# How do I do the ratio test for this series?

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Finding a Laurent series that converges for $\frac{sin(z)}{(z-{\pi}/4)^3} $:

What I have done:

Figured out that the Laurent Series can be expressed as this:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{2}*[cos \frac{n\pi}{2} +sin\frac{n\pi}{2}]*(z-\frac{\pi}{4})^{n-3}}{2*(n!)}$$

However when I attempt to do the ratio test, I am stuck at:

$$\lvert \frac{[cos \frac{(n+1)\pi}{2} +sin\frac{(n+1)\pi}{2}]*(z-\frac{\pi}{4})}{(n+1)(cos \frac{n\pi}{2} +sin\frac{n\pi}{2})}\rvert$$

Does anyone have any good guidance as to how I should proceed forward?

Would  it be more beneficial to express cosine and sine function differently? All advice is appreciated.

Edit: If you wish to know how I managed to express the series in that way, please let me know, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking from what you have there, notice that $\cos(n\pi/2) + \sin(n\pi/2)$ takes on either $-1$ or $1$. The limit then simplifies to

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left| \frac{z-\pi/4}{n+1}\right|,$$

which converges to 0.

Comment: I should note that this works only if $n$ is an integer. But, you can let $n$ approach infinity as an integer.